# blue box of death when rendering multiple flame colors

Tags: rendering, animation, smoke-simulation, fire

So Im trying to make an animated logo of an A thats on fire... but Im trying to match the original logo somewhat which has a main flame orange on the A and then blue flames coming up from further down the sides of the A. I learned through other parts of this forum that (I believe) the only way to do two different quick smokes so I can get the two different flame colors is to put them on separate layers... then select both when rendering. My problem is that a mysterious blue box starts showing up (not when I look at the rendered view, but only once it actually renders) completely ruining the output video.
[image]

At first I thought it was because on the blue layer I hadnt added anything but the flames so perhaps it just needed its own walls on that layer to reflect off of something within the layer. No luck. I cant find a way to get the phantom box to disappear... and it takes so long to render that you dont find out until an hour or so into the render (it did 30 frames in 7 hrs before I caught it this time).

For what its worth, when I open the video outside of the blender live view of it rendering, it just looks like a box without the blue tint...

Any hints or ideas or suggestions?

Comment: my only guess right now is that since I have the blue flames only coming from a smaller section of the sides of the A, this is likely the adapted top of where the smoke/flames can go so its perhaps showing up? Maybe theres a way to give it somewhat of a higher ceiling or make the area for the smoke bigger? I do have smoke adaptive domain on...

Comment: The information you posted is not enough to understand your scene and settings. Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information. We don't know how you set up your project, or the content of your layers or compositing nodes.